# Semi-commutative von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space with measure $\mu.$ Let $\mathcal M\subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra.

1. Can an element of $L_\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ be regarded as a measurable map from $\Omega$ to $\mathcal M$? A reference where the properties of $L_\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ have been studied will be appreciated also.
2. Is it true that there exists a canonical injective $*$-homomorphism $\pi:L_\infty(\Omega;\mathcal M)\to L_\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ such that $\pi(L_\infty(\Omega;\mathcal M)) $ is dense in $L_\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ in weak operator topology? In above $L_\infty(\Omega;\mathcal M)$ is all strongly measurable essentially bounded $\mathcal M$-valued functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $H$ is separable, $L^\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes} \mathcal{M}$ can be identified with the essentially bounded weakly measurable functions from $\Omega$ into $\mathcal{M}$. (Weakly measurable = its composition with any normal state on $\mathcal{M}$ is measurable.) This is a minor variation on Theorem 6.5.8 of my book *Mathematical Quantization*. Here the $\mathcal{M}_x$ appearing in that theorem aren't factors, but they all equal $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: What if the von Neumann algebra not separable? Is the same conclusion true again?

Comment: Separable predual is the nice condition you want.  Actually, for your question the measurability issues aren't so bad, so maybe you don't even need this hypothesis.

Comment: Dear Nik. Can you please sketch the proof in the present context. I understand that $L_\infty(\Omega)\otimes \mathcal M$ can be identified as a $*$-closed subalgebra of $B(L_2(\Omega;\mathcal H).$ Now the von Neumann tensor product is just the WOT closure of $L_\infty(\Omega)\otimes \mathcal M$ in $B(L_2(\Omega;\mathcal H).$ Somehow I need to associate a matrix to elements  in the closure What will be a natural candidate?

Comment: $L^\infty(\Omega; \mathcal{M})$ and $L^\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal{M}$ are the weak* closures of $L^\infty(\Omega)\otimes \mathcal{M}$ in $B(L^2(\Omega; H))$ and $B(L^2(\Omega)\otimes H)$, respectively. You see how to identify the two Hilbert spaces; now just observe that this identification respects the copies of $L^\infty(\Omega)\otimes \mathcal{M}$ in the two algebras.

Comment: Hi Nik, it seems the OP is using the definition from Banach-space world where $L^\infty(\Omega; E)$ means the essentially bounded strongly-measurable E-valued functions on $\Omega$. I think that for E an infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra this space is going to be smaller than the spatial tensor product $L^\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes} {\mathcal M}$ (issues with the Radon-Nikodym property)

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't notice that before.  (Maybe added in an edit?)  My answer applies to the set of weakly measurable functions.

Comment: @Nik. Thank you. The identification is also contained in Sakai's book on `$C^*$ algebras and $W^*$ algebras'. I have just one doubt. Clearly, not all $F:\Omega\to\mathcal M$ can be strongly measurable. So what do you mean essentially bounded weakly measurable maps. My main concern is with the `essential bounded' words? Also finally we need a Banach space. So do not we need to quotient out something?

Comment: That sounds like several doubts ... $f: \Omega \to \mathcal{M}$ is "essentially bounded" if the function $t \mapsto \|f(t)\|$ is bounded off of a null set. Every essentially bounded weakly measurable map operates in a natural way on $L^2(\Omega; H)$ and you can take $L^\infty(\Omega; \mathcal{M})$ to be this set of operators. Yes, this identifies maps which agree almost everywhere

Comment: @Nik. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Nik. I have one more question. Suppose that $\mathcal M$ is equipped with a normal faithful semifinite trace $\tau$. Then we know that $L_\infty(\Omega)\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ admits a trace denoted by $\int\otimes \tau.$ Now take a positive element $F\in L_\infty(\Omega;\mathcal M).$ Clearly, $F(w)\geq 0$ a.e. So $\tau(F(w))$ is well defined. Can we say that $w\mapsto \tau(F(w))$ is measurable? If so then then we'll simply have $\int\otimes\tau(F)=\int_\Omega\tau(F(x)).$

Comment: Ok. I can see that it is a pointwise limit of measurable functions by weak measurability and separability of L_1.